# Delphi 11 - TTreeView - How set Checkbox value for items in a node

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I would like to set all Checkboxes in a `TTreeNode`.

Is there a simpler way to do this, or is there a "Best Practices" way to do it?

For example, `TreeNode.SetAllCheckboxes:=true;`

In my example below, I can set all checkboxes to true.

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

```pascal
procedure TForm1.TreeView1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    TreeViewCheckAllNodes(TreeView1.Selected);
  end;

procedure TForm1.TreeViewCheckAllNodes(treeNode:TTreeNode);
  var
    loop:integer;
    check:boolean;
  begin
    //Check or Uncheck
    check:=true;
    if treeNode.Checked=True then check:=false;
    treeNode.Checked:=check;
    for loop:=0 to treeNode.Count-1  do
      begin
        treeNode[loop].Checked:=check;
      end;
    treeNode.Expand(true);
  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use a recursive call in your procedure CheckAllNodes.
This will check or uncheck all the way down regardless if you have more than one level below the selected node or different number of levels to the nodes below the selected.

```
procedure TForm1.CheckAllNodes(treeNode:TTreeNode; Check: boolean);
begin
   while (treeNode<> nil) do
   begin
     treeNode.Checked := Check;
     CheckAllNodes(treeNode.getFirstChild, Check);
     if treeNode<> Form1.TreeView1.Selected then
       treeNode:= treeNode.getNextSibling
     else
       treeNode:= nil;
   end;
end;


procedure TForm1.TreeView1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CheckAllNodes(TreeView1.Selected, not TreeView1.Selected.Checked);
end;
```